# Names on title page of Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, titles

We have several group members whose names should be on the title slide of a Beamer document. However, when I put something like this:

```
\author{Person A \and Person B \and Person C \and Person D \and Person E}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
\end{document}
```

Person C's name will be broken across two lines.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Box the person's name using `\mbox{Person C}` (or `\hbox{...}`). Here's a little example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\author{Dude Azerbaijan \and Dude Bangkok \and Dude Canada 
\and Dude Denmark \and Dude Ethiopia \and Dude France}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you now use `\mbox{Dude Denmark}`, the result is:

[image]

Comment: Is there an advantage of using `mbox` over a unbreakable space `~`? An if yes what is it?

Comment: @bloodworks: In this case I don't think so. `\mbox` will keep the entire box together, while an unbreakable space `~` might cause hyphenation in the names (thereby breaking the name yet again, just in a different place).

Comment: Great, this works just fine.